# Difference between non-prime and non-key attributes in Database

Tags: database, key, primary-key

I am a little bit confused between non-prime attribute and non-key attribute
I have searched a bit about them and found that 
non-prime attribute means An attribute which is never included in any candidate key. 
non-key attribute means attribute that does not uniquely identify an instance of an entity. 
What exactly is the difference between them??
 For example for a relation

```
  R (A,B,C,D,E)
   {
    AB-->E
    CD-> E
    }
```

Can you please tell me which of the attributes are non-key attributes and which of the attributes are non-prime attributes??
Sorry if this was a trivial question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prime attribute means the same as key attribute.
Non-prime attribute means the same as non-key attribute.

In your example we can deduce the key to be {A,B,C,D}; A,B,C,D are prime attributes; E is non-prime.

Answer (score -1):

If the attribute is not a member of any candidate key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).